# Rails pagination - Ajax data input with params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, kaminari

So I'm using the Kaminari gem to implement infinite scroll in my application. The problem I'm having is giving the controller the search params each time in my Ajax call.

```
def create
@onsearch = true
@lists = current_user.lists.all
@search = params[:search]
@page = params[:page]
puts "Search is #{@search}, page is #{@page}"
@outfits =  Oufits.where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per(20)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @outfits.to_csv }
  format.xls
  format.js {render :layout => false }
end
```

end

This is the ajax I call when users scroll to the bottom of the page:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data : { search : '<%= @search %>'},
    dataType: 'script',
    beforeSend: function(){
     $('.sk-wave').show();
    },
    complete: function(){
     $('.sk-wave').hide();
    },
    success: function(response){
     $('.sk-wave').hide();
     },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
     alert("oh no! ajax went wrong.")
     $('.sk-wave').hide();
     console.log("jqXHR = "+JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
     console.log("textStatus = "+JSON.stringify(textStatus));
     console.log("errorThrown = "+JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
    }
  });
 }
```

The partial that I render when I respond with Javascript is working fine and adds the rest of the content to the page perfectly..

```
$('.pagecontent').append("<%=j render(partial: 'search/outfits', 
format: 'html') %>");

<% if @outfits.current_page == @outfits.total_pages %>
 $('#view-more').remove();
<% else %>
 $('#view-more a').attr('href', '<%= url_for(page: 
 @outfits.current_page + 1) %>');
<% end %>
```

But upon inspection, the search param is received as the literal string'<%= @search %>' in my controller. I've google how to pass a erb variable to javascript but it seems far too complicated for what I'm trying to do. How then can I make sure it's passed each time? Thanks for your help

Comment: Where did you put the ajax code? Which file?

Answer (score 1):

You have a several problem:

`'<%= @search %>'` doesnt works as you expected. Assets files in the `app/assets` directroy doesnt have an access to your views variable, because it is precompiled on the server while deploying application.

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="zyx" value="<%= @search %>" />
var value = $('input#foo').val()
```

To pass a variable to `ajax` use a `hidden_input` with the value of `@search`, and fetch it by `jquery`.

`"GET"` doesnt have a body, which means your `data` key is passed as query string.

Use `"POST"`.

Comment: Oh ok thank you - I just moved my JS into the app/assets directory so that makes sense!

Comment: @Isaac sorry my ignorance, is it possible having the variable `@search` from the `create` action in `create.js.erb` file. I am kind of asking a question myself, sorry http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns